# Svelte и Spring Boot в одном проекте

Tags: intellij-idea, docker, spring-boot, svelte

Привет гуру Svelte и Spring Boot.

У меня возникла проблема с объединением этих двух фреймворком. По отдельности они работают отлично, но на сколько я знаю их можно каким то образом совместить через Docker ( возможно я не прав ). Использую Intellij. Может кто-нибудь подскажет новичку в этом не легком для него деле? Как должны распологаться эти фреймворки в папке проекта? Находил github репозиторий с тем что мне надо, но как следует у меня его запустить не удалось.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй посмотреть пример здесь https://github.com/amemifra/svelte-springboot и здесь https://github.com/amemifra/dockercompose-springboot-svelte. Внутри есть README. Там указано что у тебя должно быть установлено и какими командами это сделать. Надеюсь это поможет!

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]